# How to get the details of the video in c# sitecore?

Tags: c#, sitecore

Here i need to get the details of the video like thumbnail location,title,description,duration to use it for google video sitemap. Here i am reading the video source from webpage using Htmlagility pack. How to get these details for a media item in sitecore?

```
<source type="video/mp4" src="/~/media/7ca037b0700844cd92db1fe753a4abfc.ashx" title="720p HD">
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Is this helpful?? [http://sitecorejunkie.com/category/html-agility-pack/](http://sitecorejunkie.com/category/html-agility-pack/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have this information in your Sitecore media item.

If you get the `src` attribute using `HtmlAgilityPack`, you can then get the media item using this core:

```cs
DynamicLink dynamicLink;
if (!DynamicLink.TryParse("/~/media/14BDED00E4D64DFD8F74019AED4D74EB.ashx", out dynamicLink))
    return;
MediaItem mediaItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(dynamicLink.ItemId, dynamicLink.Language ?? Sitecore.Context.Language);
```

Then you can get all the details from the media item.

Comment: If the source is from youtube how to get the video information     <source type="video/youtube" src="https://youtu.be/73X4qpTISvs">

Comment: How to get the below details also Play page URL,
Thumbnail URL,
Raw video file URL and/or the video player URL

Comment: @Rooney Are you using some sort of 3rd party Youtube module or something you have created yourself?

Comment: @jammykam youtube api